# Rails 3.0 development for deployment on SQL-server on another operating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, windows, macos

I'm developing a Rails 3 solution for a client of mine but I don't have much experience on deployment in Rails 3.  Basicly I'm working on Mac OSX and will have my own DB with data I will receive from the ERP system from my client.  His environment exists of Windows and SQL Server, so when I deploy it will have to be agains SQL Server and Windows (he could possibly use Linux).

Most of the data will come from tables/views in sql server but 4-10 new tables will be populated by my Rails solution.

What is the best workflow in developing on MacOSX for deployment on Windows and SQL Server on Windows?

I will be using Rails 3, haml, Google-Maps-For-Rails, SASS and Blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

obviously you cant install SQLserver on mac, so you have two options

the first one, and it's possible only if your client's db is simple, is to copy the important and basics stuff from his db to your sqlite development db, and then you can work with your own clone db.

If the first option isn't possible in your case, then you need to work directly with the client's db, ask him to create for you a user (to make sure you can't harm his db) and connect remotely with rails.

here is an example

```
db_name:
adapter: sqlserver
database: db_name
host: remote_ip
username: user
password: password
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely you'll be able to directly connect to the client's SQL Server via the method mentioned above. They probably won't let their **Database** for their **ERP solution** see the light of the outside world... _ever_. So instead you may be able to get set up with VPN access and _then_ you can connect to it after you're VPNed into their network.

Answer (score 1):

A super simple answer? Use JRuby!! For sqlserver just use jdbc and **activerecord-jdbc-adapter**.

```
gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter
```

Then in database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: jdbc
  username: username
  password: p4ssw0rd
  schema: default_schema
  driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
  url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sqlserver_dns/database_name:1433
```

And here you go! Start coding now :)

When you want to deploy the final version on windows/linux/whatever just use Tomcat and Warbler.

```
gem install warbler
// in the root of your project
warble war
```

Copy the war and you have done!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have no experience in JRuby and I'm afraid that I will hit a wall in developing and especially deploying.  Do you think it is something that is "plug-n-play"?

Comment: Absolutely! Give it a try because you don't have to know Java to use it.
1. rvm install jruby
2. rvm jruby
3. gem install rails
4. rails new myNewAwesomeProject